# Why am I getting outputted a random large integer for total revenue and a 0 for average price?

Tags: c++, class

I made a class for books to sell, and was testing it out. The program runs, however it does not behave as intended.

When I input the correct types (100 copies sold, 50 sales price), I get 687194768 for my total revenue, and 0 for my average cost, which makes no sense.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Sales_Item {
    public:

        std::string ISBN;

        int copies_Sold{ };
        int sales_Price{ };
        int total_revenue = copies_Sold * sales_Price;
        int average_cost = total_revenue / copies_Sold;
};

int main()
{
    Sales_Item book;

    //Input ISBN, # of copies sold and sales price to get total revenue and average cost back, based on class parameters 
    std::cin >> book.ISBN >> book.copies_Sold >> book.sales_Price;
    std::cout << book.ISBN<< "\n" << book.total_revenue << "\n" << book.average_cost;
}
```

I put in the ISBN (which comes out correctly), put in 100 copies sold and 50 for the average price. I expect the average cost to be 50 since it is total revenue divided by copies sold, so 5000 / 100, and the total revenue should be 5000 since it's 100 copies sold * 50 sales price.

Comment: `int average_cost = total_revenue / copies_Sold;` is dividing by zero and undefined behavior.

Comment: `int average_cost = total_revenue / copies_Sold;` -- C++ does not work like a spreadsheet, where you define a formula and the program magically uses it.  Programs run top-down.  As soon as the compiler sees that line, it attempts to execute it.

Comment: Note that the compiler doesn't actually run the program. It translates the behaviour described by the code into machine instructions that execute the described behaviour when run. If the described behaviour says to compute a number before the necessary values are available, that's the program you get. Mind you, keep an eye on [the As-if Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) which says if you can't notice the difference in the program's output, the compiler can do whatever the <expletive deleted> it wants to make the program more efficient.

Comment: To create a reproducible example don't prompt for input. Assign values that show the problem.

Comment: I recommend you implement a default constructor which initializes the structure members.  With a constructor, you can set the order of initialization that makes sense to you.

Comment: FYI, in common parlance, `Sales_Item` means **one** item.  If you want multiple sales items, either create a container, e.g. `std::vector<Sales_Item>` or create a class that contains multiple sales items.  For example, the average price of one item, is usually not changed by having multiple items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All members are initialized when the instance is constructed. You want functions instead:

```
class Sales_Item {
    public:

        std::string ISBN;

        int copies_Sold{ };
        int sales_Price{ };
        int total_revenue() { return copies_Sold * sales_Price; }
        int average_cost() { 
             // avoid division by zero...
             return copies_Sold ? total_revenue() / copies_Sold : 0; 
        }
};

int main()
{
    Sales_Item book;

    //Input ISBN, # of copies sold and sales price to get total revenue and average cost back, based on class parameters 
    std::cin >> book.ISBN >> book.copies_Sold >> book.sales_Price;
    std::cout << book.ISBN << "\n" << book.total_revenue() << "\n" << book.average_cost();
}
```

Comment: In `average_cost` you need to use your other function as a function call.

Comment: Sorry if I seem dense, but can you explain to me how changing the total_revenue and average_cost to functions fixed it? Also what does the average_cost function do exactly?

Comment: @Ashton221 as I wrote, in your code, the members are initialized when the instance is created. In my code you can call the funcitons at any time and the expressions will get evaluated to reflect the current values of `copies_Sold` and `sales_Price`